# Move selection on wxPython DataViewListCtrl using hotkeys when sorted

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython 4.2.0 app that includes a `DataViewListCtrl` and some other widgets. The app has global hotkeys of CTRL+K/J that move the `DataViewListCtrl` selection up and down respectively, just as if that widget were selected and the up/down arrow keys were pressed. The problem is that when sorting by a column (which changes the default order), the hotkeys continue to use the default ordering which causes the selection to jump around. The hotkey logic uses `GetSelectedRow()` which doesn't seem to be affected by sort order, it will always return the default ordering value.

Is there a way to wire up the hotkeys so they act just like the arrow keys? Some things I've tried without luck: sending a KeyEvent to the `DataViewListCtrl`, finding native methods like `MoveSelectionUp()` and `MoveSelectionDown()` on `DataViewListCtrl`, finding the actual sort order of the `DataViewListCtrl`.

Below is a small app that shows the problem. To repro the issue behavior try the CTRL+K/J hotkeys to start then sort by the "item" column (click the header) and try the hotkeys again, note how the highlighted row jumps around rather than progressing in order like when using the up/down keys.

```python
import wx
import wx.dataview as dv

app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title="Repro", size=(300,300))
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
panel = wx.Panel(window)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)

# Another widget, the hotkeys should work when this has focus.
text = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
sizer.Add(text, proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, border=8)

# The widget affected by the hotkeys.
view = dv.DataViewListCtrl(panel)
view.AppendTextColumn("num", 120)
view.AppendTextColumn("item", 120)
view.Columns[0].SetSortable(True)
view.Columns[1].SetSortable(True)
view.AppendItem(["1", "foo"])
view.AppendItem(["2", "bar"])
view.AppendItem(["3", "qux"])
view.AppendItem(["4", "zar"])
view.AppendItem(["5", "etc"])
view.SelectRow(0)
sizer.Add(view, proportion=8, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, border=8)
max_row = view.GetItemCount() - 1

# Logic used by the hotkeys to change the selected row.
def move_up(e):
    selected_row = view.GetSelectedRow() - 1
    if selected_row < 0:
        selected_row = max_row
    view.SelectRow(selected_row)
def move_down(e):
    selected_row = view.GetSelectedRow() + 1
    if selected_row > max_row:
        selected_row = 0
    view.SelectRow(selected_row)

# Set up the hotkeys.
accels = []
id_up = wx.NewIdRef()
window.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, move_up, id=id_up)
accels.append([wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord("k"), id_up])
id_down = wx.NewIdRef()
window.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, move_down, id=id_down)
accels.append([wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord("j"), id_down])
atbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(accels)
window.SetAcceleratorTable(atbl)

window.Show(True)
window.Raise()
text.SetFocus()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance for any help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My gut feel, is that as the `wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl` is a window that hides what is really happening underneath, you may have to change to a `DataViewCtrl` and `DataViewModel`. You are after all simply modifying a `row` number, not a position on the screen. Having said all of that, I've never used one, so this is a supposition, nothing more.

Comment: @Rolf Yeah, you're probably right. I'll look into implementing a custom model to see if that would allow access to the sorting order. Thanks for the feedback!